# Mysql 8.0 installation error in windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows

Can anyone help me in installing mysql server and workbench on  windows 10(64 bit architecture).
Steps:

1. Download Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html#downloads
2. unzip and run mysql-installer-web-community-5.7.25.0.msi
3. Select standalone mYSQL server in Group Replication
4. Type and Networking--> config type: development computer, TCP/IP , PORT 3306
5. Authentication method: Use strong password encrytpion.
6. Accounts and Roles: type the password.
7. **Apply configuration**: when I click on execute it fails with below error.

> Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file
>   Invalid server template
>   Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP includes MySQL server
you can download from this link [XAMPP download](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

Comment: These are the steps i followed and it worked!
1)Download mysql server 5.7.24(Windows (x86, 64-bit), ZIP Archive) from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/
2)open cmd prompt and run mysqld -install --> this installs the mysql service
3)press Windows+R and type services.msc, you will see mysql service started.If not click on start service.
4)Open MSI installer, choose custom install and install only mysql workbech.

Answer (score 0):

There may be 2 solutions here:

1. Try to run as admin
2. change installation path
3. and why do you unzip .msi installer?

Comment: I am running as admin, tried changing installation path as well but no luck. Downloaded file was in zip format thats why unzip!